# Invertibility of operators on scales of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given a nonnegative selfadjoint operator $A\geq0$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, with norm $\|\cdot\|$, it is known that we can associate it with a scale of Hilbert spaces $\{\mathcal{H}_\alpha(A)\}_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}}$, where, for all $\alpha\geq0$, $\mathcal{H}_\alpha(A)$ is the completion of $\mathrm{Dom}\,A^{\alpha/2}$ with respect to the norm
\begin{equation}
\|u\|_\alpha=\left\|(A+1)^{\alpha/2}u\right\|,
\end{equation}
and $\mathcal{H}_{-\alpha}(A)$ is its dual with respect to this topology. In particular, $\mathcal{H}_0(A)=\mathcal{H}$.

Among the many properties of such scales, the following one holds: given $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ in the resolvent of $A$, its resolvent $(A-z_0)^{-1}$ can be interpreted as a continuous operator between $\mathcal{H}_\alpha(A)$ and $\mathcal{H}_{\alpha+2}(A)$.

I am wondering whether a similar property holds if we consider, instead of $A$ itself, some sufficiently "well-behaved" perturbation of it. Namely, let $0\neq B$ be a (possibly nonsymmetric) bounded operator on $\mathcal{H}$ such that the operator $A+B$, as an unbounded operator on $\mathcal{H}$ with domain $\mathrm{Dom}\,(A+B)=\mathrm{Dom}\,A$, admits some $z_0$ in its resolvent set, so that $(A+B-z_0)^{-1}$ is well-defined as a bounded operator on $\mathcal{H}$. Can the latter operator be also interpreted as a continuous operator between $\mathcal{H}_\alpha(A)$ and $\mathcal{H}_{\alpha+2}(A)$ for all $\alpha$, like in the case $B=0$?